# Xamarin vstool build cannot find NuGet MSBuild targets

Tags: xamarin, tfs, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-mac

**Background**

I recently converted my Xamarin.Forms app from PCL to Net Standard format. 
All of my projects now use `PackageReference` in the `csproj` file. Which means no more `package.config` or `package.json`.

We use TFS 2015 to build, sign, package our `.ipa` and `.apk` files. After conversion, the default **MSBUILD** build steps do not work as they look for `mdtool` and the new Visual Studio has `vstool` instead. So, I updated the build steps to use new tools via command line.

All my projects are NetStandard now (including iOS and Android).

**Issue**

I can successfully restore NuGet packages using `restore MySolution.sln -force` on Mac build server. But when I run `vstool build MySolution.sln` after that, I get this error:

> error: NuGet packages need to be restored before building. NuGet
>   MSBuild targets are missing and are needed for building. The NuGet
>   MSBuild targets are generated when the NuGet packages are restored.

I am able to *successfully* run the `nuget restore` and `vstool build` locally on the build machine. But only when TFS runs the command via agent, it shows that error message.

**Setup**

Builds: TFS 2015 on Mac agent running Visual Studio 7.5

Comment: Mmm, not sure what TFS is doing differently. The error message is from the .NET Core extension in VS for Mac. This error happens when the extension checks that the obj/project.assets.json file exist. This file should be generated when a restore is run. You could try switching to use msbuild instead of vstool to run the build. You can also use `msbuild /t:restore yoursolution.sln` to restore a .NET Standard project.

Comment: `msbuild /t:restore My.sln` fails with error,
`/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : '1.0.0$(rev:r)' is not a valid version string.` on all Net Standard projects. (which is the version set by my build configuration)
so, using `nuget restore My.sln` only restores PCL packages. It shows the warning,
`NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.`
Also, no `bin` and `obj` folders exist on the server because restore and build fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was finally able to get a successful iOS build on Mac server. This is the setup that works,

- Using `PackageReference` in iOS `.csproj`
- No `package.config`, `project.json`, or `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.
- Running `nuget restore .sln` before building the iOS project.
- Build solution using `<path-to-vstool>\vstool build .sln -c:<configuration>`

Now, I am working on the Windows machine for Android setup. Once I have that working, I will post my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error and your description, you need also check if your build agent has corresponding **capability** to support vsbuild.

Take a look at this related question [MacOS - Visual Studio Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/694) and give a try with this workaround:

> As a work around we set the Xamarin.iOS variable manually in the build
>   agent and changed the mdtool path in the Xamarin iOS Build step to
>   "/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/vstool".

Besides you could also try to use the suggestion from Matt in the comment above.

Comment: Yes. I do have the capability, and I did change the path to `vstool`. It works fine locally on the build server, but when run via TFS agent, it does not work. And I noticed, the `bin` and `obj` folders are not being created.

Comment: @hnabbasi  If the build is successful on the agent locally, suggest you reconfigure or reinstall the TFS build agents. The build agent will not detect the environment changes after you installed it. It will only detect during the installation. If you had manually add the capabilities in Settings- Agent Queues- Agent Pool - Agent- Capabilities, reconfigure the build agent. After this trigger the build again.